# How to use more than 3 classical registers in a single quantum circuit in Qiskit without getting error: not enough memory slots?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, measurement, quantum-circuit

I'm trying to run a quantum circuit on `qasm simulator` which has more than 3 classical registers. It gives error when I try to execute it. The circuit looks something like:
[image]

Execution failed every time and gives the following error:

```
Code:
    job = execute(qc, qasm, shots = 1024)
    job_monitor(job)
    res = job.result()
    counts = res.get_counts()
    counts

Error msg:
    Simulation failed and returned the following error message:
    ERROR: Failed to load qobj: Invalid Qobj experiment: not enough memory slots.
    Job Status: job has successfully run
    []
```

I've observed that similar circuit with less than 4 classical register works fine. But for my work I cannot reduce the number of registers further.

**Another possible way out:**
Consider a classical register of six bits for example `[abcdef]`. Now how to apply controlled operations based on group of two bits like `[ab]`, `[cd]` and `[ef]`? This way I can reduce the number of registers.

*Note:* The number of bits in the register and the number of bits in a group are not fixed. It is decided randomly, otherwise `circ.gate(qubit).c_if(cr[i]).c_if(cr[j])` would've worked.

Comment: I tested a circuit with 4 classical registers and it worked without any issue. What's your Qiskit version? And could you share the code that build the circuit?

Comment: Qiskit is updated to latest version ( qiskit  0.39.0 ). This circuit is generated using an algorithm which applies some operators randomly. The code is too long and I won't be able to share.

Comment: In my limited experience, the circuit will not run if you take multiple measurements to any single classical register.